# where can I find prestashop controllers and how can i extend them?

Tags: php, prestashop

I am new to prestashop, so please bear with me if I am asking a very simple question.
I am into creating module, and in my task I have to extend the cart controller that is being called by the ajaxcart.add() function in the javascript.
I want to know, where is the controller that responds to this ajax request is located, and how can i extend this controller in my module.
Are there any good documentation regarding this?
thanks

Comment: As A. Visser suggests, you should read the Prestashop docs. There's lots of info about extending the existing functionality. You could also look at other modules that add additional functionality to existing code.

Comment: I have added a sollution that i found while looking inside the prestashopo hood. can anybody tell me a similar way to extend the /classes/product.php?@nathangiesbrecht

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to extending the prestashop default controllers inside a module.
I looked iniside the `classes/Dispatcher.php` and found this inside the dispatch() method

```
case self::FC_MODULE :
            $module_name = Validate::isModuleName(Tools::getValue('module')) ? Tools::getValue('module') : '';
            $module = Module::getInstanceByName($module_name);
            $controller_class = 'PageNotFoundController';
            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($module) && $module->active) {
                $controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/');
                if (isset($controllers[strtolower($this->controller)])) {
                    include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/'.$this->controller.'.php');
                    $controller_class = $module_name.$this->controller.'ModuleFrontController';
                }
            }
            $params_hook_action_dispatcher = array('controller_type' => self::FC_FRONT, 'controller_class' => $controller_class, 'is_module' => 1);
```

So, The naming convention for the controller is

```
<modulename><controllername>ModuleFrontController
```

and the path to the controller should be

```
module/<module name>/cotrollers/front/<controllername>.php
```

Example mycart controller inside an areacalc module

```
class areacalcmycartModuleFrontController extends CartController {
```

File path to the mycart controller inside an areacalc module

```
/modules/areacalc/controllers/front/mycart.php
```

url will be

```
http://localhost:8080/index.php?fc=module&module=areacalc&controller=mycart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the defaut CartController.php, in the override module folder you add your class code (only the modified method) in this case i suppose you would modify the processChangeProductInCart method, you can see the [prestashop override documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingacontroller)